# React stale state issue with callback passed to children

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component that has a state. I have two child components that can accept a callback as a prop. The callback will update the state of the parent. But since both components load quickly and call the callback at relatively the same time, they end up updating the old state of the parent. What is the workaround for this? Example:

```
const Child = ({index, onUpdate}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    onUpdate("my state", index);
  }, [])
  return (
    <div></div>
  )
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [childState, setChildStates] = useState(["", ""]);
  const onUpdate = (state: string, index: number) => {
    const temp = [...childState];
    temp[index] = state;
    setChildStates(temp);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Child index={0} onUpdate={onUpdate} />
      <Child index={1} onUpdate={onUpdate} />
    </>
  );
};
```

In general I believe this is probably an anti pattern, but the reason I want the parent to know about those child states is so it can actually go and update another child components (not pictured here) state who relies on those children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) when you're updating your state based on the last state.

For example:

```js
setCount((prevCount)=> prevCount+1)
```

Instead of:

```js
const newCount = count+1;
setCount(newCount)
```

In your case:

```js
const onUpdate = (state: string, index: number) => {
    setChildStates((lastChildStates) =>
        lastChildStates.map((lastChildState, i) =>
            i === index ? state : lastChildState
        )
    );
};
```

Comment: <3 thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :)